# Text value of the picklist field. Salesforce, Dotconnect, Devart

Tags: salesforce, devart, dotconnect

I am using Devart DotConnect to access Salesforce database. And there is a problem accessing field that is a picklist. Here is part of my Enterprise.wdsl:

```
<element name="RecordType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:RecordType"/>
<element name="RecordTypeId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
```

I can do

```
SELECT RecordTypeId ...
```

and get 18-digit ID, 
but if I do

```
SELECT RecordType ...
```

I get "**Unknown column**" error

In Apex I can do

```
RecordType.Name
```

But in DotConnect it doesn't work. Is there a way to build a query to extract RecordType text value?
I know one workaround is to create a formula field and select that. But I'd prefer not to change existing Salesforce schema.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the name of Salesforce object (table) where you look for the RecordType column.

JIC: you can get the list of all columns available via interface of our provider using conn.[GetSchema](http://devart.com/dotconnect/salesforce/docs/?MetaData-GetSchema.html)("Columns", new string[]{"TableName"});

Comment: Navigate to C:\Users\{user name}\AppData\Roaming\ and remove *.db cache files named by the Salesforce.com or Database.com account name. They will be recreated on the next conn.Open(). Does this fix the issue?

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with cache. I think I need to join something but can't figure out what.

Comment: Is there the RecordType column in the result set of conn.GetSchema("Columns", new string[]{"Opportunity"}); ?

Comment: There is no RecordType column, however there is RecordTypeId column. That's why I think it needs to be Joined somewhere

Answer (score 0):

It appears I need to join RecordType table

```
SELECT f.Boo, rt.Name as RecordType
FROM Foo f
JOIN RecordType rt on f.RecordTypeId=rt.Id
```

Interestingly Salesforce documentation on RecordType object doesn't show Id column but this join works and returns expected values